# Is it possible to submit app to Appstore which is developed in Xcode 7 beta 2

Tags: app-store, xcode7-beta2

I developed app using xcode 7 beta 2 version. Can I submit it to App store

Comment: I tried upto submitting to iTunes connect . But while deploying the ipa file in iPhone it was not installing

Comment: No you can't. You need to either use the latest version of Xcode 6 (for iOS 8 and earlier) or wait until the GM release of Xcode 7 for iOS9.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. You need to either use the latest version of Xcode 6 (for iOS 8 and earlier) or wait until the GM release of Xcode 7 for iOS9.